# Error compiling native python library on windows with mingw32

Tags: python, mingw32

I'm trying to compile [python-levenshtein](https://github.com/miohtama/python-Levenshtein) on windows with python3.3 using mingw32.

I made a virtualenv, installend mingw32, downloaded the source and issued

```
python setup.py build -c mingw32
```

and I get this [error message](http://pastebin.com/xV15k0dv)

Any idea on how can I solve this?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18717996/222914) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11182765/222914) helps.

Comment: While the solution of building libpython33.a seemed A LOT the correct one, it simply didn't work :/

Comment: I endend installing visual studio 2010 and compiling with it