# Build complications with PyQt4 and SIP; how would I downgrade to Python 2.7.9 from 2.7.10 in a windows 8.1 machine?

Tags: python, windows, mingw, pyqt4, python-sip

I am new to Python and ran into a bizarre build error when trying to compile my installation of PyQt4 which I need to run as it is a dependency to another module. I was using minGW as my compiler and got a difficult and complicated build error, my logs look similar to the one in [this post](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.cython.user/13394).

However I didn't understand the resolution about remaking Python27_a. Additionally, I am not using a virtual machine. I can provide my logs if that would help but will need quite a bit of time to retrace my steps and recreate them.

Generally I was following [this guide](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/PyQT-Sip-installation-td1923578.html) (this is another instance of a similar problem) for installing PyQt4 because the installation instructions from the source were not completely clear.

Here is the Module with the dependency:
https://github.com/waveform80/compoundpi

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182765/how-can-i-build-my-c-extensions-with-mingw-w64-in-python) can bring you a step further.

Comment: A x64 Python will cause other issues with my application.